# Changing the name of Subdomains.Root Domain in cPanel or WHM

Tags: cpanel, whm

I'm thinking of migrating my site (has WHM and cPanel) to a different host (has Sentora). Since I'm just testing things out, I've decided to temporarily change the name of my subdomains, while I set them up on the new host.

While everything went without any problems on the new host, I'm having trouble renaming the subdomains on the old one. I've looked through both cPanel and WHM, and haven't found a way to actually change the subdomain name.

This is what I've found in cPanel and WHM.

[image: Cpanel]
[image]

The thing I'd like to change is the one marked in red on the first image. I thought that editing the DNS in WHM, and changing every mention of admin and user to aadmin and uuser, respectively, would solve my problem, but that's obviously not the case. I've also restarted the server, and the end result was always the same - the subdomain names have not changed.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't personally edited a subdomain's name in cPanel before. I haven't seen that as an option.

To manage subdomains, I've found that I can add them through my registrar and add nameservers. Then add them to my hosting service. I can also edit subdomain names through FTP.

If your hosting service doesn't have a platform that allows you to edit your subdomain, you may have to delete that name and add the new name. If you're worried about losing all of the files on that subdomain, you can probably just change the subdomain's name in FTP and then add the subdomain to your hosting account with correct nameservers through your registrar.